# How can I get the token value added at end of css and js files?

Tags: 7

As you know in drupal 7 css and js files added to the rendered page.
at end of href or src values you see a token.

for example

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/all/themes/uikit/css/icomoon.css?s6y431" media="all" />

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/all/themes/uikit/css/styles.css?s6y431" media="all" />
```

I want to know is there any way that I can access the variable that take "s6y431" value?

Comment: AFAIK this is not a real token, this is just a randomly generated cache buster. You could also append the current timestamp to prevent caching. (Side note: Image style variants have a "real" token to prevent DoS attacks, but for CSS and JS files this just means "hey browser, do not load an old one".)

Comment: Dear @Hudri I know what it is and what it does. But for a reason, I want to load this value. So you mean there is not any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That value is stored in a persistent variable (*css_js_query_string*) which is used by either [`drupal_pre_render_styles()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_pre_render_styles/7.x) or [`drupal_pre_render_scripts()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_pre_render_scripts/7.x).

```php
// A dummy query-string is added to filenames, to gain control over
// browser-caching. The string changes on every update or full cache
// flush, forcing browsers to load a new copy of the files, as the
// URL changed. Files that should not be cached (see drupal_add_js())
// get REQUEST_TIME as query-string instead, to enforce reload on every
// page request.
$default_query_string = variable_get('css_js_query_string', '0');
```

```php
// A dummy query-string is added to filenames, to gain control over
// browser-caching. The string changes on every update or full cache
// flush, forcing browsers to load a new copy of the files, as the
// URL changed.
$query_string = variable_get('css_js_query_string', '0');
```

Its value is initialized by [`_drupal_flush_css_js()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/_drupal_flush_css_js/7.x), but code needing it should use `'0'` as default value for *css_js_query_string*.

Comment: Thanks a lot @apaderno . It works.